# Exchange 2010 - DAG replication across sites and 2 servers - is this possible?

Tags: exchange-2010

See the image below.  I've obscured the @names, but the both mailbox servers would be on the same domain, so DAG should be possible.

Basically, is the below setup possible?

http://i307.photobucket.com/albums/nn319/dittobucket/ExpertsExchange/ExchangeIntegrationPublic-1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why not. The only issue I can see is that your 1.5MBps link is a bit on the slow side, so whenever one side goes down (e.g. for maintenance) then client access for users who have their main mailbox on that side will be slow.