# Can I copy Ex2010 databases physically before replicating them via a DAG

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, remote, dag

We have two Exchange 2010 boxes and are attempting to use DAG ([similar to this setup](https://serverfault.com/q/182410/94549) except we are less than 1 mile away from the remote office)

However we were wondering if it is possible to manually copy and paste the files necessary for replication before enabling it, so as to speed up the process.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible. It is known as manually seeding the database. You can read up on the procedure from Microsoft here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351100.aspx

The basic process involves, unmounting the active copy of the database (this will cause downtime), copying the edb file to a hard drive, remounting the active copy, copying the edb to its proper location on the new server, and adding a mailbox copy using the "SeedingPostponed" parameter.

Comment: Great this looks just like what we need. 

(tried all sorts of search terms for this except "manual seeding" - makes sense now)